# How do i show particular option for certain time limit

Tags: php, html

I want to show a particular time for a certain time like if time is more than 11 slot 11-2 should be hidden and the other two slots showed else to show all, then if time more than 2 pm above two slots should be hidden and only 6 pm -9 pm slot should be shown.
Please suggest me the proper answer using PHP

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Select Delivery Time...</option>
<option value="11:00 AM to 02:00 PM">11:00 AM to 02:00 PM</option>
<option value="02:00 PM to 06:00 PM">02:00 PM to 06:00 PM</option>
<option value="06:00 PM to 09:00 PM">06:00 PM to 09:00 PM</option>
```

Comment: do you want to filter it at loading time or check every second ? Please share you try on this ?

Comment: Is the server in the same timezone as the expected delivery?

Comment: @kumar217 is there something wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo '<option value="" selected disabled>Select Delivery Time...</option>';
if(date("H") < 11) echo '<option value="11:00 AM to 02:00 PM">11:00 AM to 02:00 PM</option>';
if(date("H") < 14) echo '<option value="02:00 PM to 06:00 PM">02:00 PM to 06:00 PM</option>';
if(date("H") < 18) echo '<option value="06:00 PM to 09:00 PM">06:00 PM to 09:00 PM</option>';
```

This assumes the server has the same timezone as your expected delivery